# Need help replicating Scrolling Text functionality from Audible in Flutter - am I doing it the right way?

Tags: flutter, scroll, flutter-animation, ui-design, flutter-text

I'm pretty new to flutter and I'm working on replicating the text scrolling feature for long track titles from the Audible app, ([see attached](https://imgur.com/a/jgbehOj)). Here's the behavior I'm trying to achieve:

• Display the long title initially - a portion of this won't be visible because it's too long.

• Pause for a predefined number of seconds, the text should wait a few seconds in this paused state before starting scrolling.

• Start scrolling the text.

• Ensure the entire text is shown via the scroll.

• After the end of the text, insert a specific number of spaces.

• As the spaces conclude, I want the beginning of the text to reappear and continue scrolling.

• The text should scroll until it seems like it's back to its original position.

• Restart the loop (wait -> scroll -> loop).

I've managed to implement most of this. However, my reset point isn't perfect ([see attached](https://imgur.com/a/SMsc4BP)). I've duplicated the text to make it scroll twice, then I reset the animation when the second set reaches the first text's start position. The timing isn't precise, causing imperfect resets.

It just feels that there's probably a better way to go about this than I have done, but I'm so new to Flutter I don't know what that way might be.

Is there a more efficient way to achieve this, or does somebody have suggestions to improve my existing code?

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:the_audiobook_app/utils/audio_player_handler.dart';

class ScrollingText extends StatefulWidget {
  final String? text;
  final double speed;
  final double containerWidth;
  final double containerHeight;
  final int spaceCount;
  final Duration delay;

  ScrollingText({
    this.text,
    this.speed = 1.0,
    this.containerWidth = 150.0,
    this.containerHeight = 50.0,
    this.spaceCount = 5,
    this.delay = const Duration(seconds: 2),
  });


  @override
  _ScrollingTextState createState() => _ScrollingTextState();
}

class _ScrollingTextState extends State<ScrollingText> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late ScrollController _controller;
  late Ticker _ticker;
  late TextPainter textPainter;
  bool shouldScroll = false;
  late String spacedText;  // Added this to ensure spaceCount is applied consistently
  double singleTextWidth = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    _controller = ScrollController();
    _ticker = Ticker(_onTick);
    //spacedText = widget.text + ' ' * widget.spaceCount + widget.text;
    //spacedText = 'Loading...${' ' * widget.spaceCount}Loading...';  // The fact this is being set here is probably not a good thing
  }

  void initializeScrollingText(String title){
    spacedText = title + ' ' * widget.spaceCount + title;

    textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(text: title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    )..layout();

    singleTextWidth = textPainter.width;

    if (textPainter.width >= widget.containerWidth) {
      textPainter.text = TextSpan(text: spacedText, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20));
      textPainter.layout();
    }

    shouldScroll = textPainter.width > widget.containerWidth;

    if (shouldScroll && !_ticker.isActive) {
      _startScrollingWithDelay();
    }
  }

  void _startScrollingWithDelay() {
    Future.delayed(widget.delay, () {
      if (mounted) {
        _ticker.start();
      }
    });
  }

  void _onTick(Duration elapsed) {
    double current = _controller.offset + widget.speed;

    if (current >= singleTextWidth) { // When the second instance is at the beginning.
      _ticker.stop();
      _controller.jumpTo(0);

      Future.delayed(widget.delay, () {
        if (mounted) {
          _ticker.start();
        }
      });
    } else {
      _controller.jumpTo(current);
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<int?>(
      stream: AudioPlayerHandler.instance.player.currentIndexStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        String title = 'Loading...';  // default text
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active && snapshot.data != null) {
          title = AudioPlayerHandler.instance.getCurrentTrackTitle() ?? 'NULL VALUE';
        }
        initializeScrollingText(title);  // Initialize scrolling for the new title

        return Container(
          width: widget.containerWidth,
          height: widget.containerHeight,
          child: shouldScroll
              ? ListView.builder(
            itemCount: 1,
            controller: _controller,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Text(spacedText,
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                  softWrap: false,
                  overflow: TextOverflow.visible);
            },
          )
              : Center(
            child: Text(spacedText.split(' ')[0], // Since spacedText has repetitions, we only take the first occurrence
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
                softWrap: true,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _ticker.dispose();
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use something like this...

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MarqueeText(
          velocity: 50,
          trailPadding: 100,
          text:
              'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incidi',
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MarqueeText extends StatefulWidget {
  final String text;
  final TextStyle? textStyle;
  final double velocity; // pixel/second
  final Duration initialDelay;
  final int trailPadding;
  const MarqueeText(
      {super.key,
      required this.text,
      this.textStyle,
      this.velocity = 150,
      this.initialDelay = const Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      this.trailPadding = 0});

  @override
  State<MarqueeText> createState() => _MarqueeTextState();
}

class _MarqueeTextState extends State<MarqueeText>
    with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late final Size size;
  bool _scrollBarDetached = false;

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    final textPainter = TextPainter(
      text: TextSpan(children: [
        TextSpan(text: widget.text, style: widget.textStyle),
      ]),
      maxLines: 1,
      textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    )..layout(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: double.infinity);

    size = Size(
        textPainter.size.width + widget.trailPadding, textPainter.size.height);
  }

  late final ScrollController _scrollController = ScrollController(
    onAttach: (position) {
      Future.delayed(widget.initialDelay, _animate);
    },
    onDetach: (position) {
      _scrollBarDetached = true;
    },
  );

  Future<void> _animate() async {
    final duration = Duration(seconds: size.width ~/ widget.velocity);

    int i = 1;
    while (true) {
      await _scrollController.animateTo(i * size.width,
          duration: duration, curve: Curves.linear);
      await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 3), () {});
      if (_scrollBarDetached || !mounted) {
        break;
      }
      i++;
    }
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _scrollController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget child = Text(
      widget.text,
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
    );

    child = Row(
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [child, SizedBox(width: widget.trailPadding.toDouble())],
    );

    return IgnorePointer(
      child: SizedBox(
        height: size.height,
        child: ListView.builder(
          controller: _scrollController,
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
          addRepaintBoundaries: true,
          prototypeItem: child,
          itemBuilder: (_, __) => child,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The basic idea is ListView keeps on repeating child when itemCount is not given.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of scroll animation is called "marquee". You need exactly this extension: https://pub.dev/packages/text_scroll

I have written one example for your case;

```
 Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Row(
        children: [
          const Expanded(flex: 2, child: Text('Static text')),
          Flexible(
            flex: 1,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.grey,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
              child: const TextScroll(
                'This is the sample text for Flutter TextScroll widget. ',
                velocity: Velocity(pixelsPerSecond: Offset(50, 0)),
                pauseBetween: Duration(milliseconds: 2000), // This will pause animation after it ends. You need this for your case
                mode: TextScrollMode.endless, 
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  )
```

Good Luck